# Using the command "sudo apt-get install openblas-dev" on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to install AlexJC's neural-enhance (https://github.com/alexjc/neural-enhance). However, I keep getting "AbstractConv2d theano optimization failed" as an error message. AlexJC states that I need to use the command "sudo apt-get install openblas-dev" however because I am running on windows and not ubuntu it does not work. Does anybody have a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Bro try installing git bash and executing this command in bash terminal. What if it worked

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to install it with Docker